# Creating SSIS Folder with PowerShell 2.0

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, powershell-2.0

I'm looking for an information that might look simple to get but i can't put my hands on it.

I wanna create a folder in a SSISDB catalog through a Powershell script, but I get an error saying that Powershell can't load assemblies : Microsoft.sqlserver.BatchParser and Microsoft.sqlserver.BatchParserClient, even though they are present in C:\Windows\Assembly.

But actually I suspect that PowerShell is running with a too old version, which is 2.0. Can anyone confirm that we can can create SSIS catalog folder with a 2.0 Powershell version ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Since no code was provided, it's terribly challenging to debug why it isn't working. However, this code is what I use as part of my ispac deployment.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null

#this allows the debug messages to be shown
$DebugPreference = "Continue"

# Retrieves a Integration Services CatalogFolder object
# Creates one if not found
Function Get-CatalogFolder
{
    param
    (
        [string] $folderName
    ,   [string] $folderDescription
    ,   [string] $serverName = "localhost\dev2012"
    )

    $connectionString = [String]::Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", $serverName)

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

    $integrationServices = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices($connection)
    # The one, the only SSISDB catalog
    $catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

    $catalogFolder = $catalog.Folders[$folderName]

    if (-not $catalogFolder)
    {
        Write-Debug([System.string]::Format("Creating folder {0}", $folderName))
        $catalogFolder = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder($catalog, $folderName, $folderDescription)
        $catalogFolder.Create()
    }
    else
    {
        $catalogFolder.Description = $folderDescription
        $catalogFolder.Alter()
        Write-Debug([System.string]::Format("Existing folder {0}", $folderName))
    }

    return $catalogFolder
}

$folderName = "ProdSupport HR export"
$folderDescription = "Prod deployment check"
$serverName = "localhost\dev2012"

$catalogFolder = Get-CatalogFolder $folderName $folderDescription $serverName
```

There may be more graceful ways of doing this within PowerShell but this gets the job done. Logically reading the above code

- Create a SqlClient connection to the server in question
- Instantiate the IntegrationServices class
- Point it at the actual catalog (assumes it has already been created)
- Test whether the folder already exists
- If the folder does not exist, create it
- If the folder exists, update the description